# Nested post object with Advanced Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a movie list to display in a page. Each movie is a post-object (which I repeat with an ACF repeater).

But in these movies, there is another post-object for the authors.

I can not see the name of the author. Can you help me ?

Here is my code

```
<?php while ( have_rows('sc_movies') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $post_object = get_sub_field('sc_movies_movie'); ?>
        <?php if($post_object): ?>
          <?php $post = $post_object; setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <article class="movie">
              <div class="movie__content">
                <h3 class="movie__title"><?= the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php $post_object = get_field('film_author'); ?>
                <?php if( $post_object ): ?>
                  <?php $post = $post_object; setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                    <span class="movie__director">Par <?= the_title() ;?> </span>
                  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </article>
         <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Try `get_sub_field('film_author')`

Answer (score 0):

please make sure if your "sc_movies" repeater has "sc_movies_movie" post object with "**Select multiple values?** =  **false** " and also in movie post "film_author" post object is  "**Select multiple values?** =  **false**" then your code is correct. If you still gettting issue try add **"wp_reset_query()"**  before while loop because may be some other post object is conflict in page.